# Windows 7 Paint program says my file name is an invalid bmp file

Tags: windows-7, bmp

I am trying to understand why this is happening. I just had paint open with my project. I extended my borders on the file and then after I saved it, I saw that message about my file name being an invalid bmp. I don't see how that could be??

What do I need to do in order to open my file back up to keep working on it??

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, did you save the file as a JPG or GIF or PNG or TIFF, and later rename it to a BMP?  If so, try renaming it to the original file type (or try each of the four in turn until you get it right.)

Failing that, right-click the graphics file and press **Restore Previous Versions**.  Select the most recent version in the list and press **Open**.  If the file is valid and what you want, you can save it to a new file.

Comment: The Paint program in Windows 7 defaults to PNG for its image format. If you typed .bmp at the end of the file it might have overridden the .png extension, despite it still being in the PNG format.